# How I can visualize elasticsearch metrics in prometheus?, both installed in a gke cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

I have a GKE cluster with this elasticseach logging solution installed

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/elastic-gke-logging

And prometheus-operator installed by helm inside the same cluster.

I would like configure a grafana dashboard for visualize metrics of my elasticsearch.

I read that elastic application from gke has the elastic_exporter installed... https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/elastic-gke-logging/README.md

But if I go to my Prometheus panel I don't see any metric about elasticsearch. I try install another elastic_exporter, but nothing.

I miss something? I forget something? Do you need to configure prometheus to read from the elastic_exporter?

I see the metrics when I do port-forwarding of the elastic_exporter, but I don't see the metrics inside prometheus panel.

```
 # HELP elasticsearch_breakers_estimated_size_bytes Estimated size in bytes of breaker
# TYPE elasticsearch_breakers_estimated_size_bytes gauge
elasticsearch_breakers_estimated_size_bytes{breaker="accounting",cluster="elastic-gke-logging-1-cluster",es_client_node="true",es_data_node="true",es_ingest_node="true",es_master_node="true",host="10.50.2.54",name="elastic-gke-logging-1-elasticsearch-0"} 4.6637464e+07
elasticsearch_breakers_estimated_size_bytes{breaker="fielddata",cluster="elastic-gke-logging-1-cluster",es_client_node="true",es_data_node="true",es_ingest_node="true",es_master_node="true",host="10.50.2.54",name="elastic-gke-logging-1-elasticsearch-0"} 0
elasticsearch_breakers_estimated_size_bytes{breaker="in_flight_requests",cluster="elastic-gke-logging-1-cluster",es_client_node="true",es_data_node="true",es_ingest_node="true",es_master_node="true",host="10.50.2.54",name="elastic-gke-logging-1-elasticsearch-0"} 0
elasticsearch_breakers_estimated_size_bytes{breaker="parent",cluster="elastic-gke-logging-1-cluster",es_client_node="true",es_data_node="true",es_ingest_node="true",es_master_node="true",host="10.50.2.54",name="elastic-gke-logging-1-elasticsearch-0"} 4.6637464e+07
elasticsearch_breakers_estimated_size_bytes{breaker="request",cluster="elastic-gke-logging-1-cluster",es_client_node="true",es_data_node="true",es_ingest_node="true",es_master_node="true",host="10.50.2.54",name="elastic-gke-logging-1-elasticsearch-0"} 0
# HELP elasticsearch_breakers_limit_size_bytes Limit size in bytes for breaker
# TYPE elasticsearch_breakers_limit_size_bytes gauge
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing `ServiceMonitor`, this should work:

```
k apply -f -<<EOF
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    release: prom
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  endpoints:
  - port: metrics
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: es-exporter
EOF
```

Your elasticsearch service must define `metrics` and have lable `app: es-exporter`, similar to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:

  labels:
    app: es-exporter
    component: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
  - name: transport
    port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9200
  - name: metrics
    port: 9108
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9108
  selector:
    component: elasticsearch
  type: ClusterIP
```

After that you should find metrics in Prometheus, to confirm that you can always use `Status -> Targets` tab in Prometheus.